# Find the value of x which would make triangles ABC and DEF congruent

Tags: geometry

["For what value of x is △ABC ~ △DEF?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MCa2.png)

Apologies for asking a highschool geometry question.

My first thoughts in solving this were to do `x^2 -5x = 84`, if you were to square root it  `-5` and `-84` would just end up as decimals. Same for `x^2 -8x = 48`.

Comment: The comment "$-5$ and $84$ aren't prime numbers" doesn't make sense. Solve the quadratic. The solutions are integers.

Comment: oops, sorry I was thinking of something else

Comment: BTW, `~` means *similar*, not congruent. Two similar triangles are congruent if they're the same size, but we have no size info about the triangles in that diagram.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if `~` was just a replacement for the congruent symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have reduced it to an algebra problem.

$$x^2-5x=84$$
$$x^2-8x=48$$

Taking difference,
$$3x=36$$
$$\therefore x=12$$

Comment: Oh, completely forgot about that, it's been awhile since I took algebra